# How to select using associated records and sql avg function from another table?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
table1
user_id  prob
1        0.33
2        0.34
3        0.35
11       0.90
88       0.80
7        0.10
8        0.11
10       0.09
12       0.80
17       0.80
18       0.80
19       0.80
20       0.80

table2
user_id  canon_id 
1        456     
2        456     
3        456      
11       4344      
88       4344      
7        2023      
8        2023      
10       2023      
12       1234      
17       1234      
18       1234      
19       1234      
20       1234
```

In the above case, how can I select records from table2 where associated table1.user_ids from table2.canon_id have avg(prob) > 0.50. In this case, canon_id 2023 and associated user_ids 7,8,10 avg(prob) is 0.10 hence it should not get selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join the `table_b` to `table_a` and aggregate to get the `canon_id`s that you want:

```
select * from table_b
where canon_id in (
  select b.canon_id
  from table_b b inner join table_a a
  on a.user_id = b.user_id
  group by b.canon_id
  having avg(a.score) > 0.5
);
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qnjUxXicjhdbfkNrR5hgyH/2).
Results:

```
| user_id | canon_id |
| ------- | -------- |
| 11      | 4344     |
| 88      | 4344     |
| 12      | 3333     |
| 17      | 3333     |
| 18      | 3333     |
| 19      | 3333     |
| 20      | 3333     |
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT table2.user_id, AVG(prob) AS prob FROM table2
INNER JOIN table1 ON table1.user_id = table2.user_id
GROUP BY canon_id
HAVING prob > 0.50
```

I used the GROUP BY to aggregate equals `canon _id` in one row, so you can use the AVG to calculate the average from aggregated row, then I used HAVING with AVG alias to satisfy the condition.

The  HAVING clause is used in the SELECT statement to specify filter conditions for a group of rows or aggregates.

The HAVING clause is often used with the GROUP BY clause to filter groups based on a specified condition. If the GROUP BY clause is omitted, the HAVING clause behaves like the WHERE clause.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

join the tables, groupby canon_id having average prob exceeding half

Try this:

```
SELECT
t2.cannon
FROM table2 t2
JOIN table1 t1 ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id

GROUP BY 1
HAVING AVG(prob) > 0.5
-- will return the canon_ids: 4344, 1234
```

As long as the following conditions hold, the above query will give you the correct answer:

- `user_id` is unique in `table1`
- the combination of `(canon_id, user_id)` is unique in `table2`

Comment: What if i want to select all the columns from table2, Would it be possible to use SELECT * or SELECT t2.canon_id, t2.user_id ... FROM. Would that change 'group by' statement?

Comment: in that case, maybe this solution presented by user @zealous. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61472059/2570261 is what you're looking for. I'm not sure. It would be best if you provided a sample output similar to the sample source tables.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. here is the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5D3yd4Npb1pT47L49aaNZu/1).

```
select
    user_id,
    avg_id
from
(
  select
    t1.user_id,
    canon_id,
    avg(prob) over (partition by canon_id) as avg_id
  from table1 t1
  join table2 t2
  on t1.user_id = t2.user_id
) val
where avg_id > 0.5
```

Comment: partition by isn't supported in my case :/

Comment: @Victor partition supported by MySQL 8.0, so assume you are  using older version of it.